# P4 protect rights for subfolders

Tags: perforce

I want to make certain folders read-only for the developers while some subfolders in that folder as write also.

For example, consider the folder structure:

```
Meeting/Jan/DevInfo/ 
Meeting/Feb/DevInfo/
Meeting/March/DevInfo/
Meeting/April/DevInfo/
Meeting/May/DevInfo/
```

I want the developers to have read permission to `//Meeting/` but write permission to `//Meeting/.../DevInfo/...`

Can I use the following code?

```
read group developers * //Meeting/...
write group developers * //Meeting/.../DevInfo/...
```

I think it should be correct, but visual in P4 shows that the whole structure of `//Meeting/` is write-allowed for developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the write access line to:

```
write group developers * //Meeting/*/DevInfo/...
```

The * character means "all files within the Meeting directory, excluding subdirectories".

The ... entry that you had before means "all files and subdirectories under //Meeting", so it overrode the following DevInfo/... section.

Try running the following to check what the protection levels are:

```
p4 protects //Meeting/...
```